Google Sheets - Import Range issue and building a formula that both Import Ranges but based on corresponding Data Validation in another column
I have a two fold question.
First issue: I have been using the formula answer provided here to importrange, and it works correctly. However making the test spreadsheets for my original question it is not working. All in Google Sheets and saved correctly. What seems to be going wrong? Using COUNTIF + IMPORTRANGE together is the Stack Overflow link where I used the longer formula, third answer.
Real issue: I would like to use this formula, or another to pull a Count of values in one column, with a specific Data Validation answer in another column, into a Master Sheet. For example, in the test spreadsheets linked below, I want to import into Sheet 2, the number of entries from Sheet 1 Column B that have Test 1 in Column A. In another cell of Sheet 2, I want to import the number of entries from Column B that have Test 2 in Column A.
=INDEX(COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet2!A1:A10")*1),
"where Col1 > 0"))))
is the formula that was working for me in my actual work, but now isn't in the test sheets I made. I was also trying to add a qualifier into it for the data validation column, but can't seem to get that to work.
Sheet 1 [where the values are] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W2Rqq3jhp-26LJ5gFNmLSl9kr5Ce4SxVcNF5Z9EiRoc/edit?gid=0#gid=0
Sheet 2 [where I want to import Sheet 1 totals] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n7_qRxslpdWZoC6mpV6HJMmyg7_l8LZPpMwaHBqIjHQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0

Can you manually enter & showcase your ideal expected output for the test data in the sheet?!

Done! Thank you!

The importrange was wrapped in IFERROR. You have to unwrap it and accept the IMPORTRANGE function to approve the transfer of data first. I did that for you and it made the total add up for you. I can take a look at the rest later if @rockinfreakshow doesn't already fix it for you :)

Oh my gosh thank you so much! You are totally right, the first time I tried the longer it didn't have that, so it prompted the approval [in my actual work]. Jotted that down on a sticky note to remember for the future, thanks again!


You may try:
=countif(importrange("1W2Rqq3jhp-26LJ5gFNmLSl9kr5Ce4SxVcNF5Z9EiRoc","Sheet 1!A:A"),"Test 1")



via QUERY()
=let(data,importrange("1W2Rqq3jhp-26LJ5gFNmLSl9kr5Ce4SxVcNF5Z9EiRoc","Sheet 1!A:A"),
     query(data,"Select count(Col1) Where Col1='Test 1' label count(Col1) ''"))



